# Can't update android studio on Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

I am trying to update my studio from version **2.2.3** to **2.3** in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am very new to Ubuntu and I can't seem to figure out as why is studio not updating. When I click **update and restart** it downloads the patches and closes and doesn't restarts. When I open it manually then it still is on the version 2.2.3 and again prompts to download and install latest version.

Answer (score 5):

I am having a similar problem while updating from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3.

Go to the bin folder of your Android Studio installation folder:  e.g. `cd opt/android-studio/bin`

Provide run permission for studio.sh file:  `chmod +x studio.sh`

Run Android Studio from here: `./studio.sh`

and try "update and restart" from android studio.

Comment: thanks I just wish I could understand why I can not use the desktop icon to launch the application and update it, but your method worked without a hitch...thanks for mentioning it